# Multiple locale GWT not working

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I want to localize my GWT project to more laguages so I added to my module.gwt.xml this section `

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" /> 
<extend-property name="locale" values="en" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="cs" />
```

I created all the properties files and interfaces but after loading module I get this exception.

```
        00:00:02,960 [WARN] Unable to get locale properties, using defaults
    com.google.gwt.core.ext.BadPropertyValueException: Property 'locale' cannot be set to unexpected value '<failed to compute>'
```

Any idea where can be the problem? Because when I have just one locale for example

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" /> 
<extend-property name="locale" values="en" />
```

it works fine.
I tried to add to avoid generating permutations for default locale but this even doesn`t work

```
<set-property name="locale" value="en, cs"/>
```

Comment: Are your resource files properly named? E.g. TextResources_en.properties, TextResources_cs.properties, etc?

Comment: Yes they are named Lokalizace_cs.properties, Lokalizace_en.properties and interface is namen Lokalizace.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en, cs" />
```

Comment: Excuese me, As Marcelo said did you try. I edited the answer maybe it helps you. And on new settings what error message do you get?

Comment: Yes I tried also your edited answer but I always get the same error message

Comment: I think there is a problem another part of your project because I tried your code and get the message you write. But correct the code as Marcelo and I said and error message disappear.

Comment: Hmm that`s strange I have no clue where the problem can be.

Comment: Yes I am editing true .gwt.xml because when I edit .gwt.xml way there are compiled only permutations for one language it works well

Answer (score 1):

If the page loads without specifying a locale through the supported mechanisms (meta tag, url param, see http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html#LocaleSpecifying for more details on how these are accomplished), it will try to fall back on a default. For that reason, you must specify a default locale to fall back on, or you get an error, as the app can't load without selecting a locale.

Set a default locale like this (from http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html#LocaleDefault):

```
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en"/>
```

If your page will always load with a default, there is no need to provide a fallback. But for testing purposes, you may find it helpful to always use one.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, As Marcelo said did you try below code.

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" /> 
<extend-property name="locale" values="en_US, cs_CZ" />
```

Could you try above code?

[Source](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html)

You could find locale values [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.4/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/CldrLocales.gwt.xml)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. I commented out locales in gwt.xml to speed up compilation process and that obviously made all locales other than English unavailable. Then when I decided to test more than one locale and uncommented locales in gwt.xml I got the same error as posted in the question (in dev mode). Only when I recompiled the project again with all locales available the error went away.